# Python: PYODBC connection link error 08S01

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc

I'm trying to use pyodbc to connect to my sql server db and create a table. I'm getting the following error:

```
cursor.execute(query1)
cnxn.commit()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-2e608ee67d50>", line 3, in <module>
    cursor.execute(query1)

OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Communication link failure (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

I'm not sure why I can't connect to sql server and create a table, however I am able to pull data from the db using SELECT statements. Can  anyone advise?

```
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import numpy as np

"""
for driver in pyodbc.drivers():
    print(driver)
"""

#define the server name, database and login credentials
server = '#########'
database ='########'
username='########'
password='########'

#define connection string
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}; \
                      SERVER=' + server +';\
                      DATABASE='+ database +';\
                      UID='+ username +';\
                      PWD='+ password +';')

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

#pyodbc.drivers()

#SQL select query to call the table Test_M_Data
sql = "SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM vintage_data"

df = pd.read_sql(sql,cnxn)

#there's python code in between but it all works fine. the problem is down below...


query1 = "CREATE TABLE Onalerona.[dbo].vintage_data_2 \
          ([ConsumerID] float,[IDno] varchar(50),[SubscriberID] numeric(11,0),\
          [OpeningBalanceAmt] numeric(19,4),[AccountOpenedDate] varchar,\
          [RetroDate] varchar,[status1] varchar(8),[status2] varchar(8),\
          [status3] varchar(8),[status4] varchar(8),[status5] varchar(8),\
          [status6] varchar(8),[status7] varchar(8),[status8] varchar(8),\
          [status9] varchar(8),[status10] varchar(8),[status11] varchar(8),\
          [status12] varchar(8),[status13] varchar(8),[status14] varchar(8),\
          [status15] varchar(8),[status16] varchar(8),[status17] varchar(8),\
          [status18] varchar(8),[status19] varchar(8),[status20] varchar(8),\
          [status21] varchar(8),[status22] varchar(8),[status23] varchar(8),\
          [status24] varchar(8),[ukey] varchar(150),\
          [stat1] varchar(8),[stat2] varchar(8),\
          [stat3] varchar(8),[stat4] varchar(8),[stat5] varchar(8),\
          [stat6] varchar(8),[stat7] varchar(8),[stat8] varchar(8),\
          [stat9] varchar(8),[stat10] varchar(8),[stat11] varchar(8),\
          [stat12] varchar(8),[stat13] varchar(8),[stat14] varchar(8),\
          [stat15] varchar(8),[stat16] varchar(8),[stat17] varchar(8),\
          [stat18] varchar(8),[stat19] varchar(8),[stat20] varchar(8),\
          [stat21] varchar(8),[stat22] varchar(8),[stat23] varchar(8),\
          [stat24] varchar(8), [Months_Diff] int, [Month_Opened] varchar,\
          [FirstArrears] varchar), [Retailer] varchar"

cursor.execute(query1)
cnxn.commit()
```

As stated earlier, my SELECT query up top works fine and I can pull the table into python and work on it, however I cannot seem to create a new table.

Comment: Creating the cursor and then handing the connection over to `pd.read_sql` might mess up the transaction for the cursor. Try moving the line `cursor = cnxn.cursor()` down the script to where you intend to use the cursor, e.g. before the line `cursor.execute(query1)`.

Comment: I tried that but I got a new error  ```    cursor.execute(query1)

ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ','. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)") ```

Comment: It's complaining about the syntax but it seems fine to me

Comment: In the last line of your CREATE TABLE statement, you close the column definition (closing parenthesis `)` after `[FirstArrears] varchar`), then you append another column definition (`, [Retailer] varchar`). That seems fishy to me.